# Remove row when same id has different eventid

Tags: sql, sql-server

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE A11 
(
    ID VARCHAR(7),
    EventID VARCHAR(5),
    index_1 INT,
    Memo VARCHAR(30)
);

INSERT INTO A11 (ID, EventID, index_1, Memo)
VALUES ('DAP', '1602', 2, 'h@gmail.com'),
       ('DAP', '1602', 78, 'female'),
       ('DAP', '1602', 79, 'not female'),
       ('179', '1601', 5, 's@gmail.com'),
       ('179', '1602', 9, 's@gmail.com'),
       ('GHJ', '1601', 89, 'male');

SELECT * FROM A11
```

Table:

```
ID  EventID index_1 Memo
--------------------------------
DAP 1602    2       h@gmail.com
DAP 1602    78      female
DAP 1602    79      not female
179 1601    5       s@gmail.com
179 1602    9       s@gmail.com
GHJ 1601    89      male
```

Now I need to sort them when `EventID = '1602'`, I will keep at least one memo with @ and another one without @.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         ID, EventID, index_1, Memo,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                                ID, EventID, 
                                CASE WHEN Memo NOT LIKE '%@%' 
                                          AND EventID = '1602' 
                                         THEN 'F' 
                                         ELSE 'Y' 
                                END 
                            ORDER BY index_1 DESC) AS SortId
     FROM 
         A11
     WHERE 
         EventID IN ('1601', '1602')
    ) g 
WHERE 
    g.SortId = 1
```

Table:

```
ID  EventID index_1 Memo        SortId
---------------------------------------
179 1601    5       s@gmail.com 1
179 1602    9       s@gmail.com 1
DAP 1602    79      not female  1
DAP 1602    2       h@gmail.com 1
GHJ 1601    89      male        1
```

However, I found out ID='179' has EventID='1601' and '1602' at the same time, but it should not happen. If an ID both have '1601' and '1602', I only want to keep the '1602' one

Expected output:

```
ID  EventID index_1 Memo        SortId
--------------------------------------
179 1602    9       s@gmail.com 1
DAP 1602    79      not female  1
DAP 1602    2       h@gmail.com 1
GHJ 1601    89      male        1
```

Is it possible to do it simply in my code shown above? Thanks

Comment: Remove `EventId` from `PARTITION BY ID, EventID`

Answer (score 0):

Partition your rows by `EventID` and then choose a representative for each part.
Something like this

```
;
WITH cteRN AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventId ORDER BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('@', Memo) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, index_1) AS RowNumberA,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventId ORDER BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('@', Memo) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, index_1) AS RowNumberB
    FROM @A11
)
SELECT * FROM cteRN WHERE RowNumberA = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM cteRN WHERE RowNumberB = 1
```

or this

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventId ORDER BY index_1) AS RowNumber
        FROM @A11
    WHERE Memo LIKE '%@%'
) T
WHERE RowNumber = 1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventId ORDER BY index_1) AS RowNumber
        FROM @A11
    WHERE Memo NOT LIKE '%@%'
) T
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```